# C# WCF: Having a single app.config in a shared library that provides access to the Service

Tags: c#, wcf, reference

I currently have a solution with a couple of projects and one of them is a WCF Service.  I created another projected with a static class that basically provides a gateway to an instance of the WCF client, like such :

```
public static class WSGateway
{
    public static DBInteractionGatewayClient MR_WebService
    {
        get
        {
            return new DBInteractionGatewayClient();
        } 
    }
}
```

This is so that (or so I thought) I could use a single `app.config` file that will be in that library only and then other projects can just just reference it and get a reference to that client from that property.

But the problem is that when a project tries to access that property, an exception is thrown telling me that I need to `app.config` in the application, and when I copy the `app.config` the my gateway library to the application, it works.

---

Is there a way to avoid having multiple `app.config` files in the application and having just one in maybe a single library?

---

**[Update] Solution:**

Following [Anderson Imes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746107/c-wcf-having-a-single-app-config-in-a-shared-library-that-provides-access-to-th/746174#746174)' suggestions, for now I decided to hardcode the client reference configuration in the class and thus eliminated the need for multiple `app.config`s.

Thus, I translated my configuration from this (`app.config`):

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IDBInteractionGateway" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="6000000"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false">
                    <security mode="None"/>
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="6000000" maxStringContentLength="6000000" maxArrayLength="6000000"
                        maxBytesPerRead="6000000" maxNameTableCharCount="6000000" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://agnt666laptop:28666/DBInteractionGateway.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IDBInteractionGateway"
                contract="DBInteraction_Service.IDBInteractionGateway" name="WSHttpBinding_IDBInteractionGateway">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

To this (a `static class`):

```
public static class WSGateway
{
    private static WSHttpBinding binding;
    private static EndpointAddress endpointAddress;

    static WSGateway()
    {
        var readerQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()
        {
            MaxDepth = 6000000,
            MaxStringContentLength = 6000000,
            MaxArrayLength = 6000000,
            MaxBytesPerRead = 6000000,
            MaxNameTableCharCount = 6000000
        };
        binding = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.None) {MaxReceivedMessageSize = 6000000, ReaderQuotas = readerQuotas};

        endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://agnt666laptop:28666/DBInteractionGateway.svc"); 
    }
    public static DBInteractionGatewayClient MR_WebService
    {
        get
        { 
            return new DBInteractionGatewayClient(binding, endpointAddress);
        }
    }
    public static void ExecuteCommand(Action<DBInteractionGatewayClient> command)
    {
        var ws = MR_WebService;
        command.Invoke(ws);
        ws.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution... that'll help other people who are trying to make this decision.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Your example is truncated, so I pasted my solution below (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/746107/c-wcf-having-a-single-app-config-in-a-shared-library-that-provides-access-to-th/7652518#7652518)

Comment: Not sure why the code is being truncated.  Anyways, here's how it should look: http://pastebin.com/8jii24JV

Comment: It does not appear to be truncated any more. There was probably a glitch in SO and it is fixed now.

Comment: any final solution with full source code sample working about it ?

Comment: @Kiquenet No; I was working on this project ~4 years ago so I can barely remember what it was about.

Comment: Thank you, this is the simplest answer to this dilemma I have yet to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get that error is that the default constructor for a WCF client proxy looks up the channel configuration from local config.  You can override this behavior by specifying the binding and address you want to use / connect to.

You have several options here, each with a different deployment model.

1. Hardcode the endpoint information in your "Gateway" library (the common term for this is "proxy").  You would just return new DBInteractionGatewayClient(binding, address);  For this solution, you'd only distribute the assembly your WSGateway code was in (hereafter called "WSGateway Assembly".
2. Create a common configuration file that all sites have access to.  If these are all services on the same machine, this is easy to do.  Place configuration data in a shared common drive location and read it from there.  If you want the full gamut of possible WCF configuration to be available, you'd need to use the ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration method and read it manually and apply it manually to your binding before your open the client channel.  For this you would ensure you centrally located config file was accessible and distribute you WSGateway Assembly.
3. Move your configuration to a common resource accessible from all applications, like a database.  This would allow you to access this configuration data from any point in your solution.  For this solution, you would ensure your configuration database was accessible from all points in your solution and distribute your WSGateway Assembly.

These are the solutions I could think of off the top of my head.  Let us know what you decide to do.

Answer (score 0):

Andreas' answer ends in a "p" so I think something didn't get copy and pasted correctly. But it put me on the right track, and I came up with this. I started from the example WCF introduction from MS (the Calculator).

This is the old method that uses app.config on the client application

```
        CalculatorClient client = new CalculatorClient();
```

This is the hardcoded version that does not require app.config. I double checked that all of the values in the app.config in the binding section are defaults and do not need to be explicitly copied. However, you can add all of these values directly to the properties of `binding`.

```
        string address = "http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service/CalculatorService";
        WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
        binding.Name = "WSHttpBinding_ICalculator"; // not sure if this is necessary.
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(address);
        CalculatorClient client = new CalculatorClient(binding, endpointAddress);
        return client;
```

Btw, I have no  idea what I am doing with all these bindings, I'm just trying to get it to work!  I just learned about WCF yesterday... I wanted to put the entire interface inside a DLL and did not want to have to copy or merge the app.config with the GUI front-end.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why but the last code snippet is not being shown properly, although the full code is included in the answer.  I've informed a moderator about it.  In the meantime, here's the full last snippet: http://pastebin.com/8jii24JV