# how much of the app.config of a WCF Service Library has to be copied over to app.config of a Console Host?

Tags: wcf

How much of the app.config from the WCF Service Library has to be duplicated in the Console Host's app.config?

Comment: Marc_s please put that excellent answer as an answer to let me up vote you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically: everything.

The `app.config` for the WCF service class library will not be read by .NET.

You need to have all the settings (more specifically: everything in `<system.serviceModel>` section) into your host application's `app.config` file.

@Broyian: WCF configuration is a notoriously difficult and often not very well understood topic. I have two video show episodes that I really like that helped me understand configuration a lot better - check them out!

- DotNet Rocks TV Show #122: [Miguel Castro on Extreme WCF](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122)
- DotNet Rocks TV Show #135: [Keith Elder Demystifies WCF](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=135)

@Broiyan: you might want to check out this blog post here about improvement in WCF 4.0 making it less of a "beast":

- [Why ASMX web services are not an excuse anymore with WCF 4.0](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2010/09/06/why-asmx-web-services-are-not-an-excuse-anymore-with-wcf-4-0.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+cibrax+%28Pablo+M.+Cibraro+%28aka+Cibrax%29%29)

Comment: Thanks. It is my impression your answer hard to discover in Lowy's chapter 1 and via Google and MSDN.  How might I find these answers without resorting to stackoverflow?

Comment: @broiyan: configuration is always a tricky business... and since those answers are hard to discover, there **is** a place like Stackoverflow!

Comment: Ok, well if it is "notoriously difficult" then I suggest to Microsoft that the MSDN website text should be changed.  Presently MSDN site says "Windows Communication Foundation is...a part of the .NET Framework that provides a unified programming model for rapidly building service-oriented applications that communicate across the web and the enterprise."  "Rapidly" should be replaced by "slowly" until this situation is better documented either by Microsoft or the programmers that post free tutorials all over the world.

Comment: Knowing that it is a beast and notoriously difficult is certainly something we should all be aware of before starting.  Thanks.

Comment: @broiyan: updated my answer yet again - another link to an interesting article about how WCF 4 is a lot easier to use (less of a "beast") than earlier versions. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand the question, but if you are trying to get rid of the app.config in a WCF client application (ie to put everything inside of a DLL), see here

[C# WCF: Having a single app.config in a shared library that provides access to the Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746107/c-wcf-having-a-single-app-config-in-a-shared-library-that-provides-access-to-th/7652518#7652518)